# In Objective-C, how can I make a typedef for a composed object?

Tags: objective-c, ocmock

I'm using OCMProtocolMock to mock a protocol. After some clean up, my object conforms to 3 protocols:

```
id<MyProtocolA, MyProtocolB, MyProtocolC>
```

`OCMProtocolMock` takes only 1 arg, so I'd like to make a typedef of my new, composed object to pass to `OCMProtocolMock`.

Something like:

```
typedef id<MyProtocolA, MyProtocolB, MyProtocolC> CombinedProtocol;

id<CombinedProtocol> _myCombinedObject = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(CombinedProtocol));
```

But that's throwing compiler error saying that it cannot find the protocol declaration for 'CombinedProtocol'.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: one time u use it as type, another you use it as @protocol. But the protocol is never properly declared. If the inheritance of your class structure that join the protocols one by one it would work. But you try to summarise that the type "CombinedProtocol" is an id that follows three protocols ending up in a definition that is something like id<id> which will not work.

Comment: what about `@protocol CombinedProtocol <MyProtocolA, MyProtocolB, MyProtocolC> @end`?

Comment: lol I beat you to it. I was trying to make it too Swift-like, where a typedef might be a good solution. Our solution here works for ObjC. Thanks!

Comment: for swift you could still inherit the protocol on an object and use typedef there for this object type. To make it short most swift converted classed do just that by decorating the type names to avoid duplicate declarations.

Comment: and.. harharrr. you could use #define for this, if you have to type it often and just don't want to make a typedef. I do this often to mark methods and properties that belong to other threads, seems like sugar but it very handy to see what the code actually does without going to deep in code reading up again after a long cofé break. cheers.

Comment: @OlSen if you post an example of that, I'd be happy to accept it as the answer. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to just define a protocol that conforms to all the others.

```
@protocol CombinedProtocol <MyProtocolA, MyProtocolB, MyProtocolC>

@end
```

And just use that like so

```
id<CombinedProtocol> _myCombinedObject = OCMProtocolMock(@protocol(CombinedProtocol));
```

And ignore the typedef entirely